How can I get full stacktrace in my C# app?
I have realized that now I'm getting short stacktrace for exceptions in my app.
E.g. I have a simple app:
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var downloader = new DataDownloader("");
}
 
internal class DataDownloader
{
    public DataDownloader(string template)
    {
        this._urlTemplate = template;
        var manager = new FileManager();
        manager.MoveFileSync();
    }
}

public class FileManager
{
    public FileManager() 
    { 
    }

    public int MoveFileSync()
    {
        try
        {
            throw new ArgumentException();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }

        return 0;
    }
}

And in catch I got simple StackTrace as

How can I get the full Stacktrace starting from the Main entry point?

Are you running your app in Release mode?

@SebastianS. nope, thats in Debug mode.

TBH not sure why this does happen but you can construct an instance of StackTrace manually and use it:
try
{
    throw new ArgumentException();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    StackTrace st = new StackTrace(true);
    Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
    Console.WriteLine("....");
    Console.WriteLine(st);
}

Demo @sharplab.io
From the Exception.StackTrace docs:

The StackTrace property returns the frames of the call stack that originate at the location where the exception was thrown. You can obtain information about additional frames in the call stack by creating a new instance of the System.Diagnostics.StackTrace class and using its StackTrace.ToString method.


Yeah, thats working.
But I'd like to do generic solution, don't like the idea of adding such code in each catch block in my app.
